# Problem on dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be the real vector space of all polynomials, in a single
>    variable and with real coefficients, of degree at most $3$.
>
> Let $V^*$  be its dual space.
>
> Let $t_1 = 1, t_2 = 2, t_3 = 3, t_4 = 4.$
>
> Which of the following sets of functionals $\{f_i |1 \leq i \leq 4\}$
>    form a basis for $V^*$?
>
> a). For $1 \leq i \leq 4,$ and for all $p \in V , f_i(p) = p(t_i)$.
>
> b). For all $p \in V , f_i(p) = p(t_i)$ for $i = 1, 2$, $f_3(p) =
>  p'(t_1)$ and $f_4(p) = p'(t_2)$.
>
> c). For all $p \in V , f_i(p) =
>  p(t_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$ and $f_4(p)=\int_{a}^{b} p'(t)dt$

---

For option a)  i'm doing just take  $f=af_1+bf_2+cf_3+df_4=0$. There exists a $p\in V$ with $p(1)=1,p(2)=p(3)=p(4)=0$ Since $f_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Applying $f$ to $p$ we find $a=0$, Similarly $b=c=d=0$ hence basis. but don't know how doing for b and c ????Thank you for help

Comment: For (a) you can probably use Lagrange polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows: just as the linear map
$$
p \mapsto \pmatrix{p(1)\\p(2)\\p(3)\\p(4)}
$$
has a trivial kernel, show that the map
$$
p \mapsto \pmatrix{p(1)\\p(2)\\p'(1)\\p'(2)}
$$
has a trivial kernel.

For c, note that we can rewrite $f_4(p) = p(b) - p(a)$.  So, whether or not the $f_i$ are linearly independent depends on the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: why we have to just  find trivial kernel???

Comment: For part a: showing that the map $T:p \mapsto (p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4))^T$ has a trivial kernel means showing that $p(1) = \cdots = p(4) = 0$, then $p$ must be zero.  If this kernel is non-zero, then we may choose non-zero vector $v = (a,b,c,d)^T \in \operatorname{im}(T)^\perp$, which would satisfy $v^T T(p) = 0$. That is to say, the $f_i$ would be linearly dependent.

Comment: ok thank you understand Now for c if b=4 then can i say it's linearly independent ??

Comment: @RAM_3R we also need to know what $a$ is

Comment: suppose a=1 ....then we can write $f_4(b)=p(4)-p(1)$

Comment: @RAM_3R actually, I misspoke: if $b = 4$, then the $f_i$ will be linearly independent for any value of $a$.  So yes: if $a=1,b=4$, the functionals in c will be linearly independent.

Comment: okkk now i understand ..thank you ..

Comment: @0mnomnomnom  Can i do this way :: take such example of four polynomial in such way which are linear independent and then showing that $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are linearly independent and in same way for c ???

Comment: @RAM_3R Yes. In fact, you could use the same polynomials that you used for part a.